# How can I rewrite a URL in Google analytics/Tag Manager

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have a website with a URL of mysite.co.uk and a webform being developed by an agency that will have a URL of subdomain.mysite.co.uk

Both will use the same tag manager container and google analytics.

However, in analytics page views to subdomain.mysite.co.uk appear as "/" which clashes with the homepage for my site. How do I tell analytics or tag manager that this a different path e.g "/webform"

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are using Universal Analytics (not the new GA4, altough his has a similar mechanism).

In the GA tag that tracks your form, go to the "more settings / fields to set" section. Here you can overwrite the default data (if you use a GA settings variable, you need to check the "Enable overriding settings" option first).

In the [field reference](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference) you can look up which field you need to overwrite. You want to set a [custom document path, and the relevant field name for that is "path"](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/field-reference#page).

So, set the field name to "path" and the value to a value of your choice, hit preview or publish, and see if you like the result.

[image: GTM field settings interface for Google Analytics]